# How to Open current directory in TotalCommander in Windows Terminal?

Tags: windows-terminal, total-commander

I'm using git-bash with Windows Terminal, I want to open current directory in a new Total Commander tab by typing a command like `tc`.

I tried to add `alias tc='D:\\programs\\totalcmd\\TOTALCMD64.EXE \/O \/T \/R="$PWD"' in` bash.bashrc`, but it has 2 problems.

1. It create a new Total Commander instance everytime.
2. It not open current directory in my git-bash

So How to Open current directory in TotalCommander in Windows Terminal (with git-bash)?